# How can i encrypt and decrypt my Cookies in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, encryption

Hello as the titles says, I'm trying to pass my cookie over pages, but I need to encrypt them and on the specific page (Home.aspx) i need to decrypt it. anyone has any idea how to?

My Code so far, Login.aspx:

```
    HttpCookie UserCookie = new HttpCookie("Login");
    UserCookie.Value = txtUsername.Text;
    UserCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(2);
    Response.Cookies.Add(UserCookie);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `MachineKey.Protect`/`MachineKey.Unprotect`

This sample code also uses `Base64` conversion to avoid getting unexpected error for invalid characters in the cookie value.

```
MachineKey.Protect(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(cookieValue), "a token").FromBytesToBase64();

Encoding.UTF8.GetString(MachineKey.Unprotect(Request.Cookies(cookieName).Value.FromBase64ToBytes, "a token"));
```

Src: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.machinekey.protect(v=vs.110).aspx

---

*Note: The above methods is extension methods to overcome null exceptions*

```
public string FromBytesToBase64(this byte[] b)
{
    return b == null ? "" :  Convert.ToBase64String(b);
}

public byte[] FromBase64ToBytes(this string s)
{
    return s == null ? null : Convert.FromBase64String(s);
}
```

Comment: This is not consistent between calls. How can be accepted as an answer?

Comment: @GabrielEspinoza  It obviously solved it for the OP, and Jason needed a variant to make it work for him, which he posted. And so can you, so go ahead, and the OP might find your better than mine and change his accepted answer to yours. .... And btw, I've been using this for my own websites the last 5 year with success so I know it is working

Comment: @LGSon could you elaborate on how you use it? because I tried to use it and everytime I called the Protect method it gave me a different string. So it was impossible to decrypt later.

Comment: @GabrielEspinoza Make sure you use the same token for both, in this case `"an authentication token"`. Can't say more now since I don't have direct access to that code piece at the moment

Comment: Where does `FromBytesToBase64()` come from, is it an extension method?

Comment: @Lankymart -- Yes, sorry, never ever though about that. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 9):

I had to change LGSon's answer slightly so it worked for me.

```
Convert.ToBase64String(MachineKey.Protect(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("your cookie value")))

Encoding.UTF8.GetString(MachineKey.Unprotect(Convert.FromBase64String("your cookie value")))
```